# Python K-Means Z-Transform

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, transform, cluster-analysis

I want to use the k-means to cluster my results, but I have a lot of question.
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans

My input data looks like this:

`ID ABC XYZ UVW MSE 
10  A   X   U  102000
12  B   Y   V  9000`

Is it possible to cluster different types of input data with the K-Means? Like in my case charakters and numbers?

K-means choose a random centre for the clustering process. If i run the clustering often will my results are changing or is the output a stable result?

I want to know, which ID is in which cluster. How i get this information out of software?

EDIT:

If I only Cluster my MSE and afterwards I check, which attributes are effected, is this solution, which makes sense?

Comment: What do you mean by Z-transform? The only Z-transform I know is the one we use in Signal Processing ... Rephrase your first two questions, they are quite confusing

Comment: I change my question i hope is get clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K-means tries to **minimize variance (=squared errors)**.

What would the squared error of `abc` and `def` be?

Only use it for continuous data. And don't expect it to do magic, what you get is usually only a very bad approximation of what you'd be looking for. Running it multiple times will usually give you different results because there exists no 'good' result.

Comment: If I standarized my variables will improve the results? When yes, which standarization are suitable (i read something about z-transformation)

Comment: No, z scores only work on data that already *is* continuous. It doesn't help you remove the artifacts from discrete/categorical data.